# Will an array of a superclass contain subclasses as well?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a class `Person`. Person contain properties like name and email. Both are from type `String`.

Beside the `Person` class, I have a subclass `Student` that inherited from superclass `Person`. Subclass `Student` contain properties like student number (`String`) and isGraduated (`Boolean`).

I have an empty array of persons from the class `Person`, like:

`var persons: [Person]()`

After I created both Person and Student objects inside the array persons, I read them out using a `UITableView`. Both models will be print in the cells. But when I want to check the value of isGraduated from the selected row, auto-completion doesn't give me the value of the property: `persons.isGraduated`.

The first thought of this problem is, will my `persons` array contain also the subclass `Student`? My second thought would be, that I think I should not check the value isGraduated inside the TableView. My wish of this function is that it will do something, like call the native camera if the person is graduated.

Looking forward to the solution.

Comment: `will my persons array contain also the subclass Student` Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @Caspert if my answer solve ur problem please mark as correct one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tree options here

A: Change the array type to Student

```
var students: [Student]()
```

B: Cast each element from the persons array to a Student. Ideally inside a for each person.

```
guard let student = person as? Student else {
     return // or continue if inside a for loop
}
```

Then u will have access to that student variable.

C: Or if they might be students and persons at the same time in the array then

```
for person in persons {
   switch person{
   case let student as Student:  //student case
      //do something
   default: //person case
      //do something 
   }
}
```

Comment: You want `guard let student = person as? Student else {`.

Comment: Yeah why? It can be a student added to the array, then the guard/casting will work.

Comment: You want to conditionally cast to the type you desire.  That will give you an optional of your desired type that either has a value or is `nil` if the type doesn't match. Then unwrap that optional with the `guard` or `if let`.

Comment: Also, in your switch, you should do `case let student as Student:` instead of the `is` + `guard`.

Comment: BTW, your `case is Person` will match students as well, so you'll never get to the `Student` check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158267/discussion-between-alegelos-and-vacawama).

Comment: @LeoDabus Good advice, but in this case i would leave it like that

Comment: Fixed , next time i will code in Xcode, not directly

Comment: Yes.  I recommended posting tested code.  If you don't have Xcode handy, then use IBM Swift Sandbox: https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl

Comment: Thanks for the answer @alegelos. Very clear and nice that you fixed it to the better way follows vacawama's suggestions! Only wondering what the best way is to call a function when isGraduated is true, like as I give in my question for example the camera for asking permission. That logic should not be live within the model, because of the MVC pattern right? I created a separate controller, but don't know where to call that function when the user touched the correct cell. Can you help me with that too..

Comment: U get the touched cell by the table delegate. It will indicate the cell by it indexPath (section and row). I would use a if isGraduated{ call camera}.

Comment: Some people consider ViewController as View and other as Controllers. If is consider part of the View, then u should call ur controller that take care of that logic. And just handle the touch event. The controller could be a singleton, a class with static methods or just a class/struct (init to use). Or use observers or delegates. That depends a lot.

Comment: In ur case I would use a static helper method to show the camera. Inside a struct, inside a utils folder.

Comment: Yes, I already make use of a struct, when creating een instance of student, you also should set the struct enum of camera or contacts. Then I would like to determine which enum is set for the selected file, and if it is the camera, it should call the camera init to ask permission for it. But I'm stuck on get calling that function. And doesn't know where I should call that function from based on the selected enum struct... If you would like I can show some code inside a chat?

Comment: @Caspert In Swift  you should use structs and create protocols defining which properties your structs should contain. Much better than subclassing.

Comment: @Caspert I have some time now, do you still wanna check that MVC out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what is the type of your person : Person or Student you can use `is` keyword like this :

```
 if persons[0] is Person {
    //if a person
} else if persons[0] is Student {
    //if a student
}
```

If you want to use a function member for your specific type, you need to **downcast the type by using the keyword `as`** like this :

```
if let person = persons[0] as? Person {
    //person is now a Person type
} else if let student = persons[0] as? Student {
    //student is now a Student type
}
```

Comment: Note:  you'll never get to the else, because `Student`s are `Person`s, so the if clause will be taken for `Student`s as well.